# How do I compare two array of objects and create new array if condition matches

Tags: node.js, arrays, dictionary

I would like to compare objects in an array and create a new

I would like to have a new Array of Objects created when

- phaseID in parentArr matches the PhaseID in childArr

In this instance the new object should push the child details along with the parent details

I have used Map and Filter however didn't get the expected output.

Thanks

```
let parentArr = [
  {
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "S(Executive)"
  },
  {
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "p(Executive)"
  },
  {
    "phaseID": 3,
    "name": "pluto1(Executive)"
  }
]

let childArr = [
  {
    "childID": 1,
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "childID": 2,
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "efg"
  },
  {
    "childID": 3,
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "hij"
  }
]
```

The Expected output is below

```
let newArr = [
  {
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "S(Executive)",
    "childNode": [
      {
        "childID": 1,
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "childID": 2,
        "phaseID": 1,
        "name": "efg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "p(Executive)",
    "childNode": [
       {
          "childID": 3,
          "name": "hij"
       }
     ]
  },
  {
    "phaseID": 3,
    "name": "pluto1(Executive)"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your requirements are not really that clear. Can you post how you expect the object to look and be more clear on what the logic conditions are please? Thanks

Comment: hi I have posted expected Array as NewArr in code which is let newArr = [{
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "S(Executive)",
    "childNode": [{
            "childID": 1,
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "childID": 2,
            "phaseID": 1,
            "name": "efg"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "p(Executive)",
    "childNode": [{
        "childID": 3,
        "name": "hij"
    }]
}, {
    "phaseID": 3,
    "name": "pluto1(Executive)"
}]

Comment: put this in the question, not the comments. Make the question as clear as possible, it could help others who come across it in the future. An increased effort in constructing a question will yield better quality answers :-)

Comment: Thanks I have mentioned in the question itself. Could you help me on this ?

Comment: Im looking now, but first I am sorting your formatting out, the question is unreadable in it's current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a simple mapping function that `.map`s the parent nodes and searches for childNodes by comparing the `phaseID`. If they match, push the childNode to the parentNode:

```js
let parentArr = [{
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "S(Executive)"
}, {
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "p(Executive)"
}, {
    "phaseID": 3,
    "name": "pluto1(Executive)"
}]

let childArr = [{
    "childID": 1,
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "abc"
}, {
    "childID": 2,
    "phaseID": 1,
    "name": "efg"
}, {
    "childID": 3,
    "phaseID": 2,
    "name": "hij"
}]

function mapResult(parentArr, childArr) {
    const result = [];
    for(const parentNode of parentArr){
        const currNode = {...parentNode};
        for (const childNode of childArr) {
            if (childNode.phaseID === currNode.phaseID) {
                currNode.childNode = currNode.childNode || [];
                const {childID, name} = childNode;
                currNode.childNode.push({childID, name});
            }
        }
        result.push(currNode);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(mapResult(parentArr, childArr));
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply the fiddle seems working I am yet to implement it in my actual project . Could you pls explain what " parentNode.childNode = parentNode.childNode ?? [];" this line is doing . I am new to javascript

Comment: ?? this operator doesnt seems to work .Getting syntax error

Comment: `??` is called Nullish coalescing operator, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator
Looks like you're using an older node-version than 14. As a workaround you can use || instead, see my update

Comment: yes this worked well . Sorry for late reply as I was unwell. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi I am stuck in another similar task .Can you help me on that?I have posted a new question

Answer (score 0):

If you want new array instead of updating existing parentArr, you can try this

```
function mapResult(parentArr, childArr) {
  const newArr = [];
  parentArr?.forEach(parentNode => {
    const result = {
      name: parentNode.name,
      phaseID: parentNode.phaseID,
      childNode: childArr?.filter(childNode => parentNode.phaseID == childNode.phaseID) || [],
    };
    newArr.push(result);
  });
  return newArr;
}
```